# Case within a case in proof

Tags: numbering, theorems

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{case}{}{}{}{}{}{:}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{casep}
\newtheorem{casep}{Case}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        \begin{casep}
            case 1
            \begin{casep}
                case 1.i
            \end{casep}
            \begin{casep}
                case 1.ii
            \end{casep}
        \end{casep}
    \begin{casep}
        case 2
    \end{casep}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Now, I want the cases within cases will be treated as sub-cases. However, as you can see from this screen-shot, within-cases are treated as separate cases. How to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: I think it would be simpler to have nested customised enumerate environments.

Comment: Theorems are not aware of nesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am effectively just working out the comment by Bernard about using enumeration environments instead of theorem environments for this. You could use the `enumitem` package to create a new enumeration environment that can be nested and looks the way you want.

I think the following does more or less what you are asking for:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{parskip} %% To test compatibility with different parskip/parindent values

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{casesp}{enumerate}{3} %% new list environment based on enumerate with a max depth of 3
%% Setting parameters for this list environment
\setlist[casesp]{align=left, %% alignment of labels
                 listparindent=\parindent, %% same indentation as in normal text
                 parsep=\parskip, %% same parskip as in normal text
                 font=\normalfont\bfseries, %% font used for labels
                 leftmargin=0pt, %% total amount by which text is indented
                 labelwidth=0pt, %% width of labels (=how much they stick out on the left because align=left)
                 itemindent=.4em,labelsep=.4em, %% space between label and text
%                 topsep=??, %% vertical space above and below list
                 partopsep=0pt, %% extra vertical space above and below if separate paragraph
%                 itemsep=??, %% vertical space after each item
                 }
%% Setting labels (and reference formats) for each depth separately
%% N.B. ref is needed even if you don't want to refer to cases because \thecasespi(i) uses it
\setlist[casesp,1]{label=Case~\arabic*:,ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[casesp,2]{label=Case~\thecasespi.\roman*:,ref=\thecasespi.\roman*}
\setlist[casesp,3]{label=Case~\thecasespii.\alph*:,ref=\thecasespii.\alph*}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    One of several things must hold, and we can perform this proof by considering each of these cases separately.

    \begin{casesp}
    \item
        This is the first case. 
        It consists of two subcases that have the same number with an additional roman number added to them.
        \begin{casesp}
        \item
            \label{similarcase}
            This is the first subcase and it is labelled so we can refer to it later. 
            It also spans more than one paragraph.

            This is the second paragraph of this subcase. 
            Notice how it is indented just like it would be if it weren't part of an item in an enumeration?
        \item By some symmetry, this subcase is in fact completely analogous to case~\ref{similarcase}.
        \end{casesp}
    \item
        The second case is relatively straightforward.
        I added some extra words to it to ensure that it would span at least two lines.
    \end{casesp}

    This paragraph wraps up the proof by noting that some conclusion holds in each of the cases that were considered.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

There are many knobs in `\setlist[casesp]{...}` that you can tweak if this look is not to your liking. See the `enumitem` [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) for more information.

Comment: The usual procedure is to ask one of the users who commented with a proper suggestion first to provide an answer and only post an answer if the user does not react or declines ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I answered because I did not get the impression that Bernard intended to write a follow-up to his comment from four days ago. Deleting this answer seems like a waste, but I will ask next time.